What is the meaning of “即采即发”“边采边发”?
Context:

今年5月，人民网启动“行进中国”大型融媒体系列调研行，340名年轻记者，耗时2个月，走访31个省区市的111座城市，前往500余个基层一线点位深入采访，“即采即发”“边采边发”，推出融媒体作品600余件，各平台总阅读量超11亿。

-- http://unn.people.com.cn/n1/2024/0830/c14717-40309207.html
I think https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28575/is-the-边～边-the-synonym-for-一边～一边 answers my question about 边...边..., but I'm not sure about 即...即..., and then what the general sense of the whole phrase is.
EDIT: 即插即用 means "plug and play", and 即 alone is an adverb meaning quickly. So maybe the whole phrase means "to quickly and simultaneously..." something, but I'm not sure what 采 and 发 are referring to.
EDIT2: Maybe "quickly and simultaneously produce and publish" the mixed media content.


.., but I'm not sure what 采 and 发 are referring to

即插即用(plug and play) is a technical jargon for electronic components with the function - "to be used (play) immediately after plug-in". Similarly, 即采即发 is a journalism jargon for "gather news and send the collected information immediately/promptly out for quick/timely publishing".

采 stands for 采訪 - gather info/interviews

发 stands 发送 or 发表 - send out/publish



即X即Y seems to be a common structure, e.g. 零食有即開即食，海鮮有即撈即煮， 盅頭飯有即叫即蒸，邊境執法有即逮即解

Yes, 隨..隨; 現..現; 邊..邊 also share the same structure/pattern.

These 2 phrases mean the same thing:
即采即发: instant collection and dissemination
边采边发: on the one hand collect, on the other hand (simultaneously) disseminate
